# smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, sms, smsmanager

Here I am trying to Send message using `SmsManager.getDefault()` as

```
    val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()

    val parts: ArrayList<String> = smsManager.divideMessage(msg+"")

    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage("+9198****91", null, parts, null, null);
```

It works fine on Samsung A50, OnePlus 3T etc. except **OnePlus GM1911 (OnePlus 7 pro)**

permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

so anyone have idea or suggestion to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check permission in code for SDK more or equal to M(Marshmallow) -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  {
      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission. SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      //  you can receive sms   
      } 
      else
      {
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission. SEND_SMS}, 411);
      }
  }
  else
  {
    //  you can receive sms          
  }
}
```

And on result of user action-

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 411) {
        if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults == null) {
             // show dialog that you need access to go ahead
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Your code here permission granted
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
             // show dialog that you need access to go ahead
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already implemented Runtime permission and it happens even also OnePlus 7 pro user accept that SMS permission....

Comment: thank you for quick response @Dipankar , but as you mentioned I already implemented Runtime permissions for same. Actually I do make sure in AppInfo it is accepted still not sending sms....